# Call custom tiles URL on Google Street View

Tags: javascript, tiles, google-street-view

I am learning how to create custom Street Views and I am stuck with the [CustomPanoramaMethod](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CustomPanoramaMethod).

How to call `getCustomPanoramaTileUrl()` after zoom change?

I've checked dozen of examples on Internet (mostly same "Google Sydney Office code") and none of them seem to work. Custom tiles are downloaded on Street View load but no further connections are set on zoom. Firebug shows no resources get after initial page load.

Is there a way to force Google StreetView to high resolution tiles on demand?

I've tried to hook up `zoom_changed` event but I can't figure out JavaScript function to force the refresh of already presented tile.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to invoke the `setPano` function on the `google.maps.StreetViewPanorama` object with the same pano that is already displayed, that should force a refresh on the `getCustomPanoramaTileUrl`